# How to list records with conditional values and non-missing records

Tags: sql, join, logic, union, subquery

I have a view that produces the result shown in the image below. I need help with the logic.

**Requirement:**
List of all employees who achieved *no less than 100%* target in ALL Quarters in past two years.

"**B**" received 90% in two different quarters. An employee who received less than 100% should NOT be listed.
Notice that "**A**" didn't work for *Q2-2016*. An employee who didn't work for that quarter should NOT be listed.
"**C**" is the only one who worked full two years, and received 100% in each quarter.

*Edit*: added image link showing Employee name,Quarter, Year, and the score.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aXy4.png

Answer (score 0):

The logic is pretty easy, it's math with quarters that is a bit of a pain.

There are 8 quarters in the last two years, so you simply need to select all the employee names in the last two years with a target >= 100%, group by employee name, and apply a HAVING clause to limit the output to those employees with `count(*) = 8`.

To get the current year and quarter, you can use these expressions:

```
cast(extract('year' from current_date) as integer) as yr,
(cast(extract('month' from current_date) as integer)-1) / 3 + 1 as quarter;
```

Subtract 2 from the current year to find the previous year and quarter.  The code will be clearer if you put these expressions in a subquery because you will need them multiple times for the quarter arithmetic.  To do the quarter arithmetic you must extract the integer value of the quarter from the text values you have stored.

Altogether, the solution should look something like this:

```
select
    employee
from
    (select employee, cast(right(quarter,1) as integer) as qtr, year 
        from your_table
        where target >= 100
        ) as tgt
    cross join (
        select 
            cast(extract('year' from current_date) as integer) as yr,
            (cast(extract('month' from current_date) as integer)-1) / 3 + 1 as quarter
        ) as qtr
where
    tgt.year between qtr.yr-1 and qtr.yr
    or (tgt.year = qtr.yr - 2 and tgt.qtr > qtr.quarter)
group by
    employee
having
    count(*) = 8;
```

This is untested.

If you happen to be using Postgres and expect to be doing a lot of quarter arithmetic you may want to define a custom data type as described in [A Year and Quarter Data Type for PostgreSQL](http://splinterofthesingularity.blogspot.com/2016/11/a-year-and-quarter-data-type-for.html)